# Why are my lstlsting captions appearing after the code?

Tags: captions, code

Why are my lstlsting captions appearing after the code?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={ML algorithms in Zeppelin.}, language=scala, ,label={lst:MLCode}]
some code...
\end{lstlisting}
```

produces a caption after the code. How do I put it at the start?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small **compilable document** that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: `captionpos=t`?

Comment: The default is to place the caption on top, so it's probably on the bottom because you've told `listings` to do so via the `captionpos` parameter that TeXnician mentioned.

Comment: Thanks to you all. OK Bob, will do next time. It is part of a big document so not easy to do. Adding captionpos=t worked. thanks!!!

Comment: @TeXnician Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `listings` describes an option called `captionpos` which controls the positioning of the caption. You may either choose `t` (top) or `b` (bottom), so in your case you want to use `captionpos=t`.